# How to combine state distribution plot and separate legend in traminer?

Tags: r, traminer

Plotting several clusters using seqdplot in TraMineR can make the legend messy, especially in combination with numerous states. This calls for additional options for modifying the legend which is available with the function seqlegend. However, I have a hard time combining a state distribution plot (seqdplot) with a separate modified legend (seqlegend). Ideally one wants to plot the clusters (e.g. 9) without a legend and then add the separate legend in the available bottom right row, but instead the separate legend is generating a new plot window. Can anyone help?

Here's an example using the biofam data. With the data I use in my own research the legend becomes much more messy since I have 11 states.

```
#Data
library(TraMineR)
library(WeightedCluster)
data(biofam)
biofam.seq <- seqdef(biofam[501:600, 10:25])

#OM distances
biofam.om <- seqdist(biofam.seq, method = "OM", indel = 3, sm = "TRATE")

#9 clusters
wardCluster <- hclust(as.dist(biofam.om), method = "ward.D2")
cluster9 <- cutree(wardCluster, k = 9)

#State distribution plot
seqdplot(biofam.seq, group = cluster9, with.legend = F)

#Separate legend
seqlegend(biofam.seq, title = "States", ncol = 2)

#Combine state distribution plot and separate legend  
#??
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `seqplot` function does not allow to control the number of columns of the legend, nor does it allow to add a legend title. So you have to compose the plot yourself by generating a separated plot for each group with the legend disabled and adding the legend afterwards. Here is how you can do that:

```
cluster9 <- factor(cluster9)
levc <- levels(cluster9)
lev <- length(levc)

par(mfrow=c(5,2))
for (i in 1:lev)
   seqdplot(biofam.seq[cluster9 == levc[i],], border=NA, main=levc[i], with.legend=FALSE)
seqlegend(biofam.seq, ncol=4, cex = 1.2, title='States')
```

[image]

========================
Update, Oct 1, 2018 =================

Since TraMineR V 2.0-9, the `seqplot` family of functions now support (when applicable) the argument `ncol` to control the number of columns in the legend. To add a title to the legend, you still have to proceed as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `seqlegend()` doesn't work when the other plots you are plotting utilizes the `groups` arguments. In your case the only thing `seqlegend()` is adding is a title "States". If you are looking to add a legend so you can customize what is in the legend and so forth, you can accomplish that by providing the corresponding `alphabet` and `states` that are used in your analysis.

The package's website has several walkthroughs and guides enumerating the various options and so forth: [Link to their webiste](http://traminer.unige.ch/documentation.shtml)

```
#Data
library(TraMineR)
library(WeightedCluster)
data(biofam)

## Generate alphabet and states
alphabet <- 0:7
states <- letters[seq_along(alphabet)]

biofam.seq <- seqdef(biofam[501:600, 10:25], states = states, alphabet = alphabet)

#OM distances
biofam.om <- seqdist(biofam.seq, method = "OM", indel = 3, sm = "TRATE")

#9 clusters
wardCluster <- hclust(as.dist(biofam.om), method = "ward.D2")
cluster9 <- cutree(wardCluster, k = 9)

#State distribution plot
seqdplot(biofam.seq, group = cluster9, with.legend = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I think you're right that `seqlegend()` doesn't work when plotting with the `groups` argument. However, I think the example data does not get messy enough to exemplify my problem. It would be very useful if `seqdplot()` with the `groups` options could modify the legend the same way as `seqlegend()`. For example, being able to modify the number of columns of the legend (`ncol`) would make the plot much more pleasing when you have several states (e.g. 11).

Comment: @Drypp I would put in a feature request / suggestion on their website as I know they push out updates quite regularly. This doesn't help you now, but it may on future projects.

Comment: Great suggestion. I will do that. I know that some of the developers frequents this site so hopefully they will see this post and add a comment.